# Markov chain, periodicity implies no equilibrium

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, markov-chains

Given an irreducible Markov chain with period $k$, I would like to show that $p^{(n)}(x,x)$ does not converge to a limit for a recurrent state $x$.

For the proof, I will find two subsequences that for one $p^{(n_l)}(x,x) \rightarrow 0$, and for the other one  $p^{(n_i)}(x,x) \rightarrow c>0$

First since the period of $x$ is $k$, pick any number $l$ that is coprime to $k$, then we have $p^{(l^n)}(x,x) = 0 \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

Now, look at the Markov chain with transition matrix (possibly infinite size) given by $P^k$ where $P$ is the original transition matrix. There exists a stationary distribution $\pi$ on the closed irreducible subset containing $x$. 
Also in this  new Markov chain, $x$ has period 1, and $x$ is also recurrent because 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \tilde p^{(n)}(x,x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty p^{(nk)}(x,x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty p^{(n)}(x,x) = \infty.$$
By the MC convergence theorem, we know $p^{(nk)}(x,x) \rightarrow \pi(x) > 0$.

Comment: If $k$ is the period, that means that $p^{(n)}(x, x) > 0$ only when $n \in k \mathbf{Z}$ and therefore $p^{(nk + 1)}(x, x) = 0.$ Observe now that the MC with transition matrix $P^k$ is aperiodic! Hence, $p^{(nk)}(x,x) \to c$ by standard results and likely $c > 0.$

Comment: @WillM. Could you elaborate a little bit on the why $p^{nk}(x,x)\to c$ by standard results?

Comment: An aperiodic, irreducible MC converges to a stationary measure.